# Wireless Mouse doesn't work after upgrading packages - Debian

Tags: debian, drivers, mouse, libraries, peripherals

My wireless optical mouse has stopped working after upgrades performed with `# apt-get upgrade`.

This is the output of `# tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```
May 23 10:30:00 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) config/udev: removing device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
May 23 10:30:00 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) Option "fd" "57"
May 23 10:30:00 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
May 23 10:30:00 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
May 23 10:30:21 GaboPC gnome-terminal[3619]: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
May 23 10:30:21 GaboPC gnome-terminal[3619]: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC kernel: [ 1676.972546] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC kernel: [ 1677.114694] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=3938, idProduct=1031
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC kernel: [ 1677.114702] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC kernel: [ 1677.114707] usb 3-4: Product: 2.4G Wireless Mouse
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC kernel: [ 1677.114712] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC kernel: [ 1677.118349] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:3938:1031.0006/input/input19
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC kernel: [ 1677.118994] hid-generic 0003:3938:1031.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 7 was not an MTP device
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/event1)
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse'
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 59 paused 0
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: always reports core events
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) input device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) input device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse', /dev/input/event1 is a pointer caps
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:3938:1031.0006/input/input19/event1"
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) input device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
May 23 10:30:39 GaboPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[596]: (II) input device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse', /dev/input/event1 is a pointer caps
```

Specifically, some lines say `UnloadModule: "libinput"` and `No input driver specified, ignoring this device.` That is why I think there's a conflict between the drivers and the upgrades I made.

The command `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/input/event1` returns this:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:3938:1031.0005/input/input18/event1
N: input/event1
S: input/by-id/usb-MOSART_Semi._2.4G_Wireless_Mouse-event-mouse
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0-event-mouse
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0-event-mouse /dev/input/by-id/usb-MOSART_Semi._2.4G_Wireless_Mouse-event-mouse
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:3938:1031.0005/input/input18/event1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
E: ID_MODEL=2.4G_Wireless_Mouse
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=2.4G\x20Wireless\x20Mouse
E: ID_MODEL_ID=1031
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0108
E: ID_SERIAL=MOSART_Semi._2.4G_Wireless_Mouse
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=MOSART_Semi.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=MOSART\x20Semi.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=3938
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/3938/1031/110:usb-0000:00:14.0-4
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=65
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1124309036
```

Of course the mouse is not listed in the output of `lsusb`

This is the log of `apt`

```
libavutil55:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-libswresample2_7%3a3.2.14-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libswresample2:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-libavcodec57_7%3a3.2.14-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavcodec57:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-libavformat57_7%3a3.2.14-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavformat57:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-libavresample3_7%3a3.2.14-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavresample3:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-libpostproc54_7%3a3.2.14-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpostproc54:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../8-libswscale4_7%3a3.2.14-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libswscale4:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../9-libavfilter6_7%3a3.2.14-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavfilter6:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) over (7:3.2.12-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up libavutil55:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Setting up libswresample2:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3-2) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Setting up libswscale4:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up firefox-esr (60.7.0esr-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up libpostproc54:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (74.0.3729.169-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Setting up libavresample3:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up libavcodec57:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up libavformat57:amd64 (7:3.2.14-1~deb9u1) ...
Setting up libavfilter6:amd64
```

EDIT: 
This is the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 3938:1031  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This are the last lines of the output `dmesg`

```
[Jun13 12:43] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  +8.249459] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  +3.350851] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  +0.110577] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=3938, idProduct=1031
[  +0.000009] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000004] usb 1-1.2: Product: 2.4G Wireless Mouse
[  +0.000004] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
[  +0.029435] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:3938:1031.0004/input/input17
[  +0.000881] hid-generic 0003:3938:1031.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input0
[  +0.000081] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  +0.000001] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

Comment: 1) It's very important to know what you tried; 'I have tried several answers without any success' does not tell us the result of what you tried nor does it tell us what to avoid. Please click [edit] and tell us what you tried and what result appeared on the terminal screen. Please do not reply via [Add Comment] as when comments pile up, old comments get pushed off the page. 2) If your mouse Bluetooth or does it use a proprietary dongle? Please also advise via [edit]. 3) Silly to ask, but have you checked to make sure the mouse wireless is not switched off & that it has fresh batteries?

Comment: Please edit question with actual output of `lsusb`, both syslog and udevadm show a mouse USB dongle (?) that does seem to be connected... Also, please type `dmesg`, remember the timestamp of the last line, remove the mouse USB dongle, connect it again, type `dmesg` again and edit question with the additional lines that appear.

Comment: From could you unplug the USB dongle, run `modprobe -r usbhid` and plug the dongle back in again, does that help ?

Comment: can you post output for this command `libinput debug-events` ?